# IFileProvider Azure File storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I am thinking about implementing `IFileProvider` interface with Azure File Storage.
What i am trying to find in docs is if there is a way to send the whole path to the file to Azure API like `rootDirectory/sub1/sub2/example.file` or should that actually be mapped to some recursion function that would take path and traverse directories structure on file storage?

just want to make sure i am not missing something and reinvent the wheel for something that already exists.

**[UPDATE]**

I'm using Azure Storage Client for .NET. I would not like to mount anything.
My intentention is to have several `IFileProviders` which i could switch based on `Environment` and other conditions.

So, for example, if my environment is `Cloud` then i would use `IFileProvider` implementation that uses Azure File Services through Azure Storage Client. Next, if i have environment `MyServer` then i would use servers local file system. Third option would be environment `someOther` with that particular implementation.

Now, for all of them, `IFileProvider` operates with path like `root/sub1/sub2/sub3`. For Azure File Storage, is there a way to send the whole path at once to get `sub3` info/content or should the path be broken into individual directories and get reference/content for each step?

I hope that clears the question.

Comment: AFAIK, you could [mount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows) your file share and access it just as the local file system. Also, you could leverage the storage client library to access your file storage, more details you could refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files). I could not understand your requirement correctly, could you update your question with more details about the feature or scenario you are handling?

Comment: @BruceChen Thanks for your comment. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, for all of them, IFileProvider operates with path like ˙root/sub1/sub2/sub3. For Azure File Storage, is there a way to send the whole path at once to getsub3` info/content or should the path be broken into individual directories and get reference/content for each step?

For access the specific subdirectory across multiple sub directories, you could use the `GetDirectoryReference` method for constructing the `CloudFileDirectory` as follows:

```
var fileshare = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient().GetShareReference("myshare");
var rootDir = fileshare.GetRootDirectoryReference();
var dir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference("2017-10-24/15/52");
var items=dir.ListFilesAndDirectories();
```

For access the specific file under the subdirectory, you could use the `GetFileReference` method to return the `CloudFile` instance as follows:

```
var file=rootDir.GetFileReference("2017-10-24/15/52/2017-10-13-2.png");
```

Comment: huh...i am pretty much sure i have tried exactly that and it didnt work but since it feels like you know what you are talking about i will try again and doublecheck. Should that work for create if it doesnt exist too?

Comment: In my opinion, you need to make sure the parent folder exists when creating the subfolder/file.

Comment: I tested the creating subfolder/file, if the parent folder does not exist, you would get the 404 error.

Comment: and just to clarify, by parent folder you mean the one on which we call getreference&create methods, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you want to add subfolder or file under a specific folder, you need to make sure the specific folder exists.

Comment: yes thats what my tests shown too. thank you very much for your time and explanations!